# Xamarin Forms add text to byte array

Tags: xamarin.forms

I can take photo and insert it to database as blob:

```
byte[] imageArray = null;
var photo = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions()
{
   DefaultCamera = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.CameraDevice.Rear,
   CompressionQuality = 40,
   CustomPhotoSize = 40,
   PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight,
   MaxWidthHeight = 1500,
});
if (photo != null)
{
   using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
   {
      Stream stream = photo.GetStream();
      stream.CopyTo(memory);
      imageArray = memory.ToArray();
   }
}
```

I need to add a simple text to imageArray before inserting it into database. For C# I found some way using Bitmap, Graphics libraries etc, but I could not figure out implementing for Xamarin Forms. (both Android and iOS)

Comment: You can add text on the image using Graphics. After that convert the bitmap to a byte array

Comment: if you want to overlay text on an image, you can do that with SkiaSharp